# Creating WebApplication fixture for integration tests in NET7 throws

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit, fixtures

I want to create WebApplication fixture so I can share it among my integration tests. That's how it looks:

```
public class WebAppFixture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;

    const string WsHubPath = "/";

    public WebAppFixture()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

        builder.Services.AddUltraWs()
            .AddWsHub<TestWsHub>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.MapUltraWs<TestWsHub>(WsHubPath);

        _server = app.GetTestServer();
        HttpClient = app.GetTestClient();
    }

    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    public Uri WsHubUri => new Uri(_server.BaseAddress + WsHubPath);
    public WebSocketClient CreateWebSocketClient() => _server.CreateWebSocketClient();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
        HttpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But when I want to use it in my test class:

```
public class WsHubTests : IClassFixture<WebAppFixture>
{
    private readonly WebAppFixture _webAppFixture;

    public WsHubTests(WebAppFixture webAppFixture)
    {
        _webAppFixture = webAppFixture;
    }
}
```

Then I get following exception:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer'.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: WebAppFixture webAppFixture)
> ---- System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer'.
> ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: WebAppFixture webAppFixture

How to fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? Why not use the built-in class instead, and override the configuration parts you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem does not lie with the `IClassFixture<WebAppFixture>` and the accompanying constructor parameter but with what happens in the `WebAppFixture` when it's constructed. A hint to what is going wrong is given in the error you have posted.

`(Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer'.)`

If you put a breakpoint in the WebAppFixture constructor and try to step over the line where you assign the result of GetTestServer to _server you will get an unhandled exception

[image]

This is because you are using `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()` instead of `WebApplicationFactory<TEntrypoint>`. So if we [check integration testing examples from microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs.Samples/blob/main/test/integration-tests/IntegrationTestsSample/tests/RazorPagesProject.Tests/IntegrationTests/BasicTests.cs) for some examples and modify them slightly to accommodate your situation.

```
public class WebAppFixture : IDisposable
{
    public readonly HttpClient TestServerClient;

    public WebAppFixture()
    {
        TestServerClient = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, context) =>
                {
                    //context.AddInMemoryCollection();
                });
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    //services.AddTransient<SomeService>();
                });
                builder.UseEnvironment("LOCAL_TEST");
            }).CreateClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TestServerClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your test class is unchanged and you can test your implementation using `_webAppFixture.TestServerClient`

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestSomething()
{
    var result = await _webAppFixture.TestServerClient.GetAsync("/WeatherForecast");
    IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> autoParsedResult = await _webAppFixture.TestServerClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>("/WeatherForecast");

    Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    Assert.Equal(5, autoParsedResult.Count());
}
```

Links you want to take a look at:

- [Here you can read everything about Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [Samples by the dotnet team on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs.Samples/tree/main/test/integration-tests/IntegrationTestsSample)

Comment: But now I cant use minimal API because the `Configure` method gives me `IApplicationBuilder` instead of `WebApplication`

Comment: Your question does not mention the use of minimal APIs anywhere. For future question if you do use something that might have an impact, like minimal APIs, it's good to mention this

Comment: This also works just fine with minimal APIs. Why would you think this wouldn't?

Comment: @Szyszka947 why don't you use WebApplicationFactory from the start? The [doc examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) work with minimal APIs and show how to [customize the factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-webapplicationfactory)

Comment: Oh, yes it can work with minimal APIs. I forgot about `app.UseEndpoints()`. Thanks you!